# Prove that $\mathcal{T}=\left\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R},[n,\infty):n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Prove that $\mathcal{T}=\left\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R},[n,\infty):n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is my attempt:

Clearly, $\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\in \mathcal{T}$. For the union closure, it is clear that $\mathbb{R}\cup [n,\infty)=\mathbb{R}\in \mathcal{T}$ and $\emptyset \cup [n,\infty)=[n,\infty)\in \mathcal{T}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Next, if there exists a finite collection of intervals $[n,\infty)$ in $\mathcal{T}$, then there exists a minimum $n$ such that the union will be this interval, which is assumed to be in $\mathcal{T}$.

> I am having trouble for when the collection of intervals is infinite. Do I use the well-ordering principle for the left endpoints? For example, if $[n_{1},\infty),[n_{2},\infty),...\in \mathcal{T}$, can I guarantee a minimum left endpoint?

Next, the intersection of a finite collection of intervals is clearly in $\mathcal{T}$, since there exists a maximum left endpoint that will cause the intersection to be that interval, which is assumed in $\mathcal{T}$.

Any advice is appreciated. :~)

Comment: Mostly good.  I would make the observation that $[n_1,\infty) \subseteq [n_2,\infty)$ whenever $n_2\leq n_1$ and that allows you to conclude an arbitrary union results in $[(\min(n_1, n_2, \ldots ), \infty)$ and finite intersections result in $[\max(n_1,n_2, \ldots ),\infty)$ (Note intersections must be finite, as otherwise you could end up with an open interval instead of a half-open one.)

Comment: For infinite union you should use well ordering property of naturals otherwise seems ok